# How to change JSON value schema in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, mongodb, mean-stack

I am fetching data from `excelsheet` and converting it into the `JSON` format using `xlsx-to-json` in Node.js

All the values of JSON data are by default showing on `string` format like:

```
var jsonObj = [
 { 
 id: '101', // string
 email: 'user1@test.com',  //string
 name: 'user1',
 dob: '1990-10-10',
 phone: '1234567890', //string
 country: 'England',
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz'
 },
 { 
 id: '102',
 email: 'user2@test.com',  
 name: 'user2',
 dob: '1990-10-11',
 phone: '1234567890',
 country: 'Australia',
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz'
 },
 { 
 id: '103',
 email: 'user3@test.com',  
 name: 'user3',
 dob: '1990-10-12',
 phone: '1234567890',
 country: 'France',
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz'
 }
 ];
```

When I'm inserting this `json` into mongodb all the values are getting stored in `string` datatype.

What I want to do is to validate all this schema and change its datatype before inserting it into mongodb.

Example: id & phone = `number` or `integer`, email, name = `string`, dob=`DATE`, address=`TEXT` and country = `ENUM`

Final output should be like:

```
var jsonObjResult = [
 { 
 id: 101, //integer
 email: 'user1@test.com', //string 
 name: 'user1', //string
 dob: '1990-10-10', //Date
 phone: '1234567890', //number
 country: ['England', 'Australia', 'France'], // enum
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz' // text
 },
 { 
 id: '102', // integer
 email: 'user2@test.com',  //string
 name: 'user2', // string
 dob: '1990-10-11', //date
 phone: '1234567890', // number
 country: ['England', 'Australia', 'France'], // enum
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz' // text
 },
 { 
 id: '103', //integer
 email: 'user3@test.com',  //string
 name: 'user3', // string
 dob: '1990-10-12', //date
 phone: '1234567890', //number
 country: ['England', 'Australia', 'France'], // enum
 address: 'Building 201-A, Abc, Xyz' // text
 }
 ];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may simply use regex !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a valid data in MongoDB, you must to validate your input for example with Conform (fork of Revalidator - https://www.npmjs.com/package/conform). With option 'castSource' it will cast values of source object and then you will insert data with correct type into your db.

```
var Conform = require('conform');

var myData = {
    intField: '123'
};

// after validate intField will be casted to integer
var validateResult = Conform.validate(
    myData,
    {
        properties: {
            intField: {
                type: 'integer'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        cast: true,
        castSource: true
    });

if (validateResult.valid) {
    // insert myData to db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little example of how to do it, you will have to add the missing parsers on your own.

First create a parser, this is simply just an object that provides a function for every object key that needs to get transformed.

```
var parsers = {
    id: parseInt,
    dob: function(str) {
        return new Date(str);
    },
    phone: parseInt
};

// This will parse the object and apply the transform parsers from above, calls the callback when finished
var parseObject = function(obj, callback) {
    var counter = 0;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index, array) {
        if (parsers.hasOwnProperty(key) /* && typeof parsers[key] === 'function' */) { // typeof check is not really needed, when he trust that we only define functions in our parser above
            obj[key] = parsers[key](obj[key]);
        }
        if (++counter === array.length) {
            callback && callback(); // call the callback when all parsers have run
        }
    });
};

var parseJson = function(json, callback) {
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        parseObject(json[i], function() { // parses all the objects
            if (++counter === json.length) {
                callback && callback(); // call the callback when all objects have been parsed
            }
        });
    }
};

parseJson(jsonObj, function() {
    console.log(jsonObj); // outputs the parsed object when everything is done.
});
```